# How to stop url extension from being rewritten to lowercase in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have created a basic app that renders out different pages to serve up a list of users on different teams. I have a list of the teams specified in the code:

```
pages = ['SysOps', 'NetOps', 'DBOps']
```

Within page_view it calls an external method that performs an API call and returns a list of objects, based on the name of the team that is passed in. Below is the function:

```py
@application.route('/<team>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def page_view(team):
  context = { 'team': team, 'item': getApiData(str(team)), 'pages': pages }
  return render_template('index.html', **context)
```

I pass the pages list as part of the context and have a jinja for loop iterate over it to create a navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  {% for page in pages %}
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('page_view', team=page) }}"><font size="3em" color="white">{{page}}</font></font></a>
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

On my test machine clicking on the navbar link for SysOps routes to `localhost:5000/SysOps` successfully. However, when I manually enter the url with, it is immediately rewritten to `localhost:5000/sysops`, which does not render the correct page as it's not the right case.

How do I stop the url from changing to lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that since all urls will be redirected as lower case.
Your only option is to make the pages list all lower case or send the page data to the route as a `POST` request.Instead of accepting it as a url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

All websites urls go to lowercase, for example FACEBOOK.COM, or any other website you will be redirected to a lowercase version; facebook.com

Comment: I want everything after the slash to remain in the correct case, such as with `https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWars/` Yes, the url itself is lowercase, but the actual page is partially capitalized.